# How do I use messages with third-party views?

Tags: django, notifications, django-views, message

I've implemented a notification bar using `django.contrib.messages`. Now, I want to make extended use of it, e.g. to display a "Welcome back" or "Logout successful" messages. However, I prefer to use builtin views for basic actions, so I use `django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login` for logging out and `django.contrib.auth.views.login` for logging in. Therefore, there isn't a single place where I could insert my `messages.success(...)`, since those views are not mine.

Is there an elegant way to add those messages nevertheless without copying or overwriting views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/) are your friends. See in particular the [login and logout signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#topics-auth-signals).

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about those!